# delete an array element in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, octave

In MATLAB, we can delete an object by

```
o = obj();
delete o;
```

Can we explicitly delete an object in an array?

```
arr = {obj(), obj(), obj()};
delete arr{1}; % ???
```

Also, does MATLAB release the memory if we call delete explicitly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, this line

```
delete o;
```

does not do what you think it does. In *command syntax*, o is interpreted as a string, and this will delete a file named "o" in your current working directory.

If you want to delete the object `o` then you need to use *functional syntax*, i.e.

```
delete(o);   % where o is an object in the workspace.
```

However, this does not do what you think it does either!
"Deleting" destroys an object referenced by a *handle*, i.e. **graphics object handles** (like plots) or **matlab objects inheriting from the *handle* superclass**. Note that the "handle" variable `o` itself is still on your workspace, and it points to a now deleted object!

If what you have is simply a normal variable / object and you just want to remove it from the workspace, you just `clear` it instead.

Secondly, arr is not an 'array', it's a cell array. This is a bit of a pedantic point, but an important one, since matlab *does* allow normal arrays of objects.

Thirdly, yes, to answer your question, there is a way to explicitly delete / remove an object in an array, such that the array is spliced back together. The way to do this is by assigning as an element of that array an empty element, i.e.

```
arr = {obj(), obj(), obj()};
arr(1) = [];
```

matlab's garbage collector takes care of things under the hood, you do not need to explicitly handle memory in this sense.

---

PS. All the above also apply to octave.